# SharePoint Designer - Pause until

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I want to accomplish this using SharePoint Designer and OOTB features.

Requirement : List with details - employee name , start date , end date.
30 days prior to end date send an email , 15 days prior to end date send an email.
On end date change , email should be send according to new end date.

Workflow : on item added and item created.

Solution (tried) : 
On item created, pause until [end date - 30] , once workflow comes out of pause ,send mail and pause for [end date - 15], workflow comes out of pause ,send mail.

Problem / Issue : Item created, workflow is on Pause till [end date-30]. 
If i change the end date , workflow remains in pause and does not refresh for new end date. I tried to get the steps to check weather end date has changed , if yes them stop the workflow. But how to start the workflow again.

Any other steps that I can follow to achieve the requirement?

Comment: I have the exact same issue with the pause until date. Were you able to get around this?

Comment: I have exact same issue, were you able to find a workaround for this problem?

Comment: Same kind of question here: [link](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/251004)

Answer (score 4):

Once you stop the workflow, the instance is terminated so you cannot restart. You cannot have effective solution for the problem using SharePoint designer out-of-box workflow activities.

There other solution you can consider :

1. Go for custom timer jobs instead of workflow.
2. Program a state machine workflow.

Comment: i agree with your point of "Once you stop the workflow, the instance is terminated so you cannot restart."

Comment: See my reply. If the workflow is terminated due to a change in the item, it will restart.

Comment: You cannot restart an instance of a workflow that has been cancelled or terminated. To reuse the workflow, you must start a new instance....which is what your solution does

Answer (score 2):

You need to run two actions in parallel: one that watches the date and the other that monitors changes. It is well explained here:

http://amarkeev.wordpress.com/2011/11/11/item-expiration-reminders-in-sharepoint-using-workflow/

Comment: I wish you would have included a little bit about what that site said because it is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

First you start the workflow on item created and update event.
Create a new hidden field in the list
In Pause Until Date statement - update the hidden field
This time the workflow for the update event execute
Check the current date with end-date and send the mail

I think this will resolve your issue

Comment: but what about if date is modified second time...things will not work as previous instance is already in progress.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to the question I asked myself.

We can set a retention policy to start the workflow when the *Date is reached* condition is met.

I guess it's possible only in SP 2013.