# SharePoint Workflow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2007

I have to send email notification in workflow after every 1 hour. I don't want to create timer job because all my other activity are going in workflow as I have to set task item url with email notification.

How to send email notification in workflow after every 1 hour in SharePoint Moss?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do something like this in a workflow, you would need to come up with a method for pausing a workflow (this was added as a workflow action in 2010).  The answer to this question has some ideas that might work for you: [SharePoint Designer - Pause until](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/sharepoint-designer-pause-until)