# Designer Workflow Pause until... runs at wrong time when date column modified

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow

We have a 2013 SharePoint Designer workflow with a **Pause until...** action.  It is based on a Date-Time column. I've set it to run both on item creation and update.

The problem comes in if the user changes the value of the date column. Since the workflow was already running it doesn't start again with the new value.

I found [this old thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/23290/sharepoint-designer-pause-until) but the mail post that seems to answer it is a dead link and the others say to use a timer job. Lots of other sites I've found say use a timer job or nintex -- neither of which are available to us.

Basically I think I need to have a workflow on update that stops existing workflows and then restarts. But I'm not sure how to do that. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have to use the "Parallel Block". On one side, use the Pause until action, with your current date, and on the other side, Wait for field change in current item. If the date changes, stop your workflow.

Set your workflow to start when item is modified.

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This looks useful, but I've got Wait for Event in list item and Wait for field change in current item. Neither of which give me the ability to do not equal.

Comment: Evidently in SPD13 you can only do "equal to" but I got around that with a SPD10 workflow. Also I think I need to add a Stop to my Step2 because otherwise the other parallel block is still waiting for something that will never end...

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the difference between the SPD10 and SPD13 workflow. I have designed the workflow using the SPD10 Workflow because SPD13 is not available (we use Nintex). But I'm a little bit surprised that "not equal to" is not available...

Comment: @JayHell i need similar thing to be done at my end, but i did not fully understand how you are trying to achieve this. Now in Step-3 you are checking for "Wait for Due Date to not equal Variable org due Date", but when someone update an item, and he changes the Due Date, then inside the workflow steps, the Variable "org due date" will also get updated, and as a result the variable "org due date" will also be equal to the item "Due date" is this correct ??