# Sharepoint Email

Tags: column, email, view, alert

I want a daily email to be sent that contains either the items contained on particular list view on that day, or that contains items that has a date format field set as that days' date.  (Note that the email must be sent every day, so I can't simply use the Alert function within SP, as this depends on a change being made on items to fire the alert.  Also, I want the email to contain the field values for the items, not just a URL link to them)

I'm using SP 2013 and have access to SP Designer too.

How can I achieve this please?

Comment: So...  Did you try out my Answer or did you find another method to get this to work?

Comment: Ah good, I'm glad that worked.  I do enjoy collecting the reputational points, so if you wouldn't mind marking the question as complete, I can then bask in the glory of collecting a few more points! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I posted an answer to a similar kind of question before - [here's the link to it](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240326/repeat-a-workflow-every-year/240332#240332).

You could try these methods.

### Method 1

Use Windows Task Scheduler - this allows you to set recurrent tasks, you would set it to run daily. The Windows Task Scheduler task can be used to run a powershell script that would, in turn, trigger a custom Sharepoint Designer Workflow.

Your SPD workflow criteria would specify which tasks should trigger an email to the user.

e.g. IF `Task Status` not equals Completed email the `Assigned To` person.

You can use SPD to insert a summary utilising the SP list fields - it would insert the field:value from your list e.g. task name, due date, % complete and notes etc.  You can also include a link to the item (let me know if you need help on this and I'll update the answer).

The fields circled in red are Sharepoint List fields:
[image: example SPD workflow]

### Method 2

Use the built-in Information Management Policy Settings - accessed via the List/Document Library menu.  An email can be triggered off a date field and can also be used to run a SPD workflow.

### Method 3

I just re-read your question, so I'll try to be a bit more specific.  You could create a view with a filter of `Due Date` = [Today].  The 'create view' screen itself gives some guidance on this too.

You could incorporate the 'Due Date' view (right click and copy the view url from the browser) as a simple link in the daily email (see Method 1 or 2 for instructions on how to trigger the daily reminder email).

### Method 4 (alternative to all of the above - requires people to work differently)

You could consider creating a view of the task list and the users just have to get in the habit of going to the task list every day to check their tasks.  You can make it easy for them my creating a view that filters on:

```
Assigned To = [Me]
```

and

```
Due Date = [Today]
```

OR even Assigned To = [Me] and Due Date = [Today]+7 (or is it -7) -> to give them an overview of tasks due in the coming week.