# I need to create an auto-generated email when items in a Sharepoint list are approaching a milestone date

Tags: outgoing-email

I need to be able to send an auto-generated email to the item owner when a milestone date is imminent

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options - you can use Windows Task Scheduler for this, if you have access to the server.  Or you could try using the built-in Sharepoint Information Management Policy function to trigger an email.

My answer in [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/240326/repeat-a-workflow-every-year/240332#240332) should get you started.  I'm using SP 2013 On-Premises, if you're using a different version of Sharepoint that might chance how you approach this task.

Also Windows version seems to have an effect on how to use Windows Task Scheduler - Just do a search on **Windows Task Scheduler** and you'll find a guide for your version - e.g. [this site](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard).

Answer (score 1):

A 3rd option could be to use a timer based azure function to check (searchl for items about to expire. The email could use either a SMTP service of your choice or the SendGrid service